# How to estimate the phenotypic variation explained by top SNPs from a GWAS study?

Tags: r, variance, gwas

I have conducted a large-scale GWAS study and got a few significantly associated SNPs. I used `GEMMA` with `-lmm 1` options to run the GWAS and obtain the `beta` and `standard-error` estimates. I want to estimate the percent phenotypic variation explained by each of the significant SNPs. I used the following procedure for estimating the variance explained in R:

```
fit <- lm (Phenotypic_value ~ SNP_data, data = a)
summary(fit)$r.squared
```

Here, the datafile `a` contains three columns namely, `sample_ID`, `Phenotypic_value` for each sample, and the biallelic `SNP_data`. I got a value which is 0.43 meaning 43% phenotypic variation explained by the SNP.

Again, I used another formula which is: `2*f*(1-f)*b.alt^2`. Here, `f` is the minor allele frequency and `b.alt` is the effect size i.e. `beta` estimate obtained from `GEMMA`. This gives me a value of 0.03 meaning 3% variation explained which seems reasonable to me.

My question is that which of the following method is correct? or Is there any other way to estimate the percent variation explained?

Alternatively, from the `GEMMA` google group, I have got this formula `pve <- var(x) * (beta^2 + se^2)/var(y)`. But I do not understand how can I obtain the value of `var(x)` and `var(y)`.

It will be great to receive some feedback on this. Thank you.